# Does Kubernetes kubelet support Docker Credential Stores for private registries?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubelet

Docker has a mechanism for retrieving Docker registry passwords from a remote store, instead of just storing them in a config file - this mechanism is called a [Credentials Store](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store).  It has a similar mechanism that are used to retrieve a password for a specific registry called [Credential Helpers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-helpers).

Basically, it involves defining a value in `~/.docker/config.json` that is interpreted as the name of an executable.

```
{
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

The value of the `credsStore` key has a prefix `docker-credential-` pre-pended to it and if that executable (e.g. `docker-credential-osxkeychain`) exists on the path then it will be executed and is expected to echo the username and password to `stdout`, which Docker will use to log in to a private registry. The idea is that the executable reaches out to a store and retrieves your password for you, so you don't have to have lots of files laying around in your cluster with your username/password encoded in them.

I can't get a Kubernetes kubelet to make use of this credential store.  It seems to just ignore it and when Kubernetes attempts to download from a private registry I get a "no basic auth credentials" error.  If I just have a `config.json` with the username / password in it then kubelet works ok.

Does Kubernetes support Docker credential stores/credential helpers and if so, how do I get them to work?

For reference, kubelet is running through `systemd`, the credential store executable is on the path and the `config.json` file is being read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the moment of writing Kubernetes v1.14 does not support credential helpers as per official docs [Configuring Nodes to Authenticate to a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry)

> Note: Kubernetes as of now only supports the auths and HttpHeaders section of docker config. This means credential helpers (credHelpers or credsStore) are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kubernetes has the same mechanism called [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) but with extended functionality, and it includes [specific secret type called docker-registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#creating-a-secret-with-a-docker-config). You can create your specific secret with credentials for docker registry:

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey \
 --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER \
 --docker-username=DOCKER_USER \
 --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD \
 --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL

secret "myregistrykey" created.
```

and use it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: awesomeapps
spec:
  containers:
    - name: foo
      image: janedoe/awesomeapp:v1
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```

Comment: No, this is not the same mechanism at all.  The `imagePullSecrets` mechanism you describe means you need to put your secrets in etcd, which is absolutely not the same as putting them in an enterprise-level secrets vault.  I also don't see how Kubelet can access things like its infra containers when standing up the cluster by relying on the mechanism you describe.